# Static image in Crystal Report displays line on edge (not a border)

Tags: image, crystal-reports

This is probably a long shot, but I have vague sense I ran across this many years ago so I'm hoping someone can help.

I have a static image in a Crystal Report page header that acts as a letter head. Everything looks fine in the designer, but at run-time the image displays a black line along the bottom of the image. Kind of like a border, but the line is only about a third of the width of the image and aligned to the right.

Borders for the image are set to none. I also set the image border color and background color to white. The original image was slightly large, so I resized it in Photoshop to fit the page width, thinking maybe the line was an artifact of Crystal resizing it. No joy. The image is a Jpeg but I've also tried PNG and bitmap.

The other compounding problem is I can't test the report directly on my development machine due to database connectivity issues, so the only way to test is to copy the report file to the user's machine and run it there. Additionally, the user doesn't have Crystal itself but a viewer application my predecessor wrote many years ago. So I wonder if the problem is the user's machine or settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by upgrading the user's Crystal Reports viewer application. I'm not sure what version of Crystal it was built with, but I'm doing report design in XI. I created a new viewer application and the problem cleared up.

Answer (score 0):

You may check to make sure that the image's drop-shadow formatting option isn't set. It's on the border tab if you go to the picture's properties. This is a long-shot, but I decided to throw it out there anyhow. Hope it helps.